# Problems getting the request status in node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I Already saw the other posts about this and they didnt help me. 
(Ill use r.sC to say response.statusCode)
My questions are

- What do you need to require in your file for the r.sC to work
  (I.e. require('express');)
- Is the r.sC a node object or a express object
- What are the reasons it could be undefined/ not working
- Is there a package i want to reinstall to be sure its not because its wrongly installed
- Is there a work around (by that i mean a real work around not just making it work by default for the 200/201 status and being unable to catch the rest like all the work around i saw since now)

Im using the latest stable version of both node and express

If you cant reply to all my questions just tell me the answers to the one you know, i'll be very happy to make it work with your advices. If something is unclear feel free to ask me in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure that's a node object 
And i think if you do the npm update of node it will install the files missing if they are some